# Does vfmaq_f32 really have higher running accuracy?

Tags: c++, arm, neon

Does vfmaq_f32 really have higher running accuracy?
I guess the accuracy of vfmaq_f32 varies depending on the length of the bit extension of the floating point processing unit in different architectures,on macos arm64,the result of running the code is consistent.
Can higher or lower precision results be obtained on other architectures? Or are there compilation options that can control the accuracy of the results?

```
#include<arm_neon.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    float a = 12.3839467819;
    float b = 21.437678904;
    float c = 4171.42144;
    printf("%.17f\n",a);
    printf("%.17f\n",b);
    printf("%.17f\n",c);


    printf("%.17f\n",a+b*c);

    float32x4_t a_reg = vdupq_n_f32(a);
    float32x4_t b_reg = vdupq_n_f32(b);
    float32x4_t c_reg = vdupq_n_f32(c);
    float32x4_t res_reg = vfmaq_f32(a_reg, b_reg, c_reg);
    float res[4] = {0.f};
    vst1q_f32(res,res_reg);
    printf("%.17f\n",res[0]);


    res_reg = vmlaq_f32(a_reg, b_reg, c_reg);
    vst1q_f32(res,res_reg);
    printf("%.17f\n",res[0]);


    res_reg = vmulq_f32(b_reg, c_reg);
    res_reg = vaddq_f32(res_reg, a_reg);
    vst1q_f32(res,res_reg);
    printf("%.17f\n",res[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please, don't spam tags. With `#include <iostream>` and `using namespace std`, this is definitely no C source code (or an essential syntax error). Btw. as you are new, it couldn't hurt to take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Point of that accumulating NEON asm instruction is optimization - you do one operation instead of two. Unless somethign is wrong with implementation. That is used alot when writing some impulse filters. All NEON instructions are pretty IEEE754-compliant. Doing one addition at time cannot decrease accumulation losses, you need at least three values to be summed at same time to get _any_ diffrence.

Comment: In general contracted floating point operations are _not_ IEEE754 strict mode compliant. Not checked with NEON, but they are certainly not for x86.

Comment: @Scheff's Cat
 Thank you very much for your guidance on questions, which I will focus on in future questions

Answer (score 1):

In general merged floating point operations can maintain a higher running precision. The fused multiply accumulate and dot product operations are the two that most commonly show up in instruction sets. There is no guarantee that the output of these operations is consistent across CPU architectures.

When compiling normal C code (i.e. no intrinsics) for "strict" IEEE floating point compliance the compiler must not generate these contracted operations, as they are not conformant to the specification.

Comment: Off-topic: in shared pseudocode of `FPRoundInt()` there is "If EXACT is TRUE, set FPSR.IXC if result is not numerically equal to op." comment. Here the EXACT should probably be INEXACT (and the `boolean exact` should probably be `boolean inexact`). Consider raising an issue with the spec team.

Comment: Off-topic: Arm® Architecture Reference Manual for A-profile architecture (ARM DDI 0487J.a (ID042523)) uses both `FP16` ("FEAT_FP16, Half-precision floating-point data processing") and `FPHP` ("Floating Point Half Precision"), which seems to refer to the same thing. Why using both `FP16` and `FPHP` instead of a single one (e.g. `FPHP`)? Consider raising an issue with the spec team.

Comment: For the `FPRoundInt()` case, the spec is correct as far as I read it. (I.e. if in `exact` mode, set `FPSR.IXC` if the result is not exact).

Comment: For the `FPHP` case, the register field covers more than just `FEAT_FP16`, so they are not directly analogous. I suspect the naming is deliberately different to avoid the confusion. 

The `FPHP` field can indicate an implementation with no half-float support, an implementation with fp16 conversions, or an implementation with fp16 conversions and fp16 data processing. Only the latter requires `FEAT_FP16`.

Comment: FYI: In my case `cat /proc/cpuinfo` reported [`fphp` instead of `fp16`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78107453/1778275). Initially I was confused because the manual uses `FEAT_FP16` and not `FEAT_FPHP`. Then I understood that `cpuinfo` is not required to use feature names from the manual. However, how does a user know the exact meaning of `fphp` feature reported by `cat /proc/cpuinfo`? Does the `fphp` indicate "support for fp16 conversions and fp16 data processing" OR "support for fp16 conversions" only? Any ideas / comments?

Comment: See https://docs.kernel.org/arch/arm64/elf_hwcaps.html

Comment: "HWCAP_FPHP  = Functionality implied by ID_AA64PFR0_EL1.FP == 0b0001."