# Why doesn't /proc/cpuinfo contain fp16 if FEAT_FP16 is supported?

Tags: linux, arm, half-precision-float

I know that in my ARM `FEAT_FP16` is supported.

I expect seeing `fp16` in the list of features reported by `cat /proc/cpuinfo`:

```
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep fp | sort -u
Features        : fp asimd evtstrm aes pmull sha1 sha2 crc32 atomics fphp asimdhp cpuid asimdrdm jscvt fcma dcpop asimddp asimdfhm
```

Here we see that `fp16` is not present in this list. Why?

Comment: I believe it should be 'fphp' and not 'fp16', if it is working.  In order to set this, the configuration options 'VFPv3' needs to be active.  The code looks at the `MVFR1` to determine if the features is present.  In order to get 'VFPv3', we need CPUv7 and VFP defined. https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/vfp/vfpmodule.c?h=v6.8-rc7#n940

Comment: It looks like it is only using CPU_V7 and not CPU_V7M.  What is the actual model of CPU you have?  Although, if you are using Ubuntu, it should have many CPUs configured (to be handled by the kernel; only one is active at a time), so the option should be active.  Err, indeed it is in the line 'fphp', just after atomics.

Comment: @artlessnoise Indeed, it seems that it is named [`fphp`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/929ed21dfdb6ee94391db51c9eedb63314ef6847/arch/arm64/kernel/cpuinfo.c#L62) rather than `fp16`. Why ideas why?

Comment: Because, it is half precision floating point, which takes 16 bits of data.  The others are referred to as 'double precision' and 'single precision', not fp64 and fp32.  A question could be why use fp16?  Feel free to self answer.

Comment: I put back the [tag:arm] and [tag:half-precision-float] tags which are perfectly reasonable for this question.  It's just that [tag:linux] needed to be *added*.

Comment: @artlessnoise Re: "why use fp16?: because ARM reference manual uses fp16. However, I understand that `cpuinfo` is not (?) required to use feature names from the manual.

Comment: Yes, the IEEE standards (and compiler people) will use the term 'half-precision'. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-precision_floating-point_format  Some one would be upset if they choose **fp16**.  I think **fphp** is a lesser evil. but would any choice be correct to everyone?  Again, you can self answer this question so that other people will not be confuse.  I empathize, but I don't think it was a mistake to use **fphp**.

Comment: Also, https://stackoverflow.com/tags/half-precision-float/synonyms is interesting.  Imagine a world where languages were not context sensitive nor ambiguous.  Gotta go code :)

Comment: `FPHP` is the name of the field in the feature register, so it's a reasonable choice.  ARM *now* uses `FP16` as the official mnemonic for the feature, but that naming scheme was a later addition to the spec.  The first version of the ARMv8-A spec (A.a) describes 16-bit floating point support, and uses `FPHP` for the corresponding bitfield, but doesn't contain the string `FP16` anywhere.  I couldn't find the first commit of the Linux code, but it may well predate ARM's `FP16` nomenclature.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks! I've [informed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77102788/does-vfmaq-f32-really-have-higher-running-accuracy/77107494#comment137782976_77107494) user solidpixel.

Comment: @NateEldredge A simple question: does the `fphp` (reported by `cat /proc/cpuinfo`) indicate "support for fp16 conversions and fp16 data processing" OR "support for fp16 conversions" only? Have a look at solidpixel's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77102788/does-vfmaq-f32-really-have-higher-running-accuracy/77107494?noredirect=1#comment137787125_77107494).

Comment: @pmor: A [few lines below the code linked by artless noise](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/vfp/vfpmodule.c?h=v6.8-rc7#n961), you can see that the `FPHP` flag in the kernel is set if the value in the corresponding field of `MVFR1` is 0x3, indicating full fp16 support including data processing instructions.  The conversion instructions (e.g. `fcvt h0, d1`) are part of base ARMv8-A, not associated with any particular FEATure, and should be supported by every machine that has any floating point support at all.